# ListBox on change event, with one item

Tags: javascript, listbox, onchange

I am using asp.net listBox, with the attribute rows=1.
I want that when I select an item in the listBox, the "onchange" method will call a javascript function.
The problem is that the "onchange" method doesn't start if I select the first item in the list box. I think that's because it's selected by default.

do you know any solution?

thanks

Comment: can you add the first option to be `---------` so it forces the user to select something else thus triggering the onchange ?